# Basic cube area calculation (Expected a ")")

Tags: c++

New to working with C++, just trying to do a cube calculation using 3 functions. However, when I call my calculation function in main, I get an error saying "Error: expected a ')'"

Not sure what's up.

```
//Programmer: Kevin Shick
//Date: 03/05/2015
//Lab #1 - Cube Functions

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int getCubeSide();
void calcCube(int cubeSide);
void display(int cube);

int main()
{
     getCubeSide();
     calcCube(int cubeSide);
     display;

    system("pause");
}

int getCubeSide()
{
    int cubeSide = 0;
    cout << "Please enter an integer to calculate the size of your cube: " << endl;
    cin >> cubeSide;

    return cubeSide;
}

void calcCube(int cubeSide)
{
    int cube = (cubeSide * cubeSide * cubeSide);

}

void display(int cube)
{
    cout << "The area of your cube is: " << cube << endl;
}
```

Comment: calcCube(int cubeSide) in main?

Comment: `calcCube(int cubeSide);` is not a call. Due to the `int` it's more like a botched declaration of a function. Anyway you need to declare the variable `cubeSide` before it's used. Also, `display;` is not a call since it lacks an argument parenthesis.

Comment: Have you experience with another programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Thre are multiple errors:
1) You don't store the result of `getCubeSide`
2) You use the function signature to call `calcCube(int cubeSide)` instead of `calcCube(<value>);`
3) You try to call display without the parenthesis and parameter `display; <-> display(<value>);`
4) In general you seem not to know, that all the variables like `cubeSide` or `cube` are local variables, which are only valid inside the respective function. Although they have the same name, there is e.g. no relation between `cubeSide` in `calcCube` and `getCubeSide`.

Seems to me, you should learn how to properly use functions and the general basics of the language.

Comment: In addition, `calcCube` doesn't actually use the result of the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int getCubeSide();
int calcCube(int cubeSide); //might be easier if this returns an int
void display(int cube);

int main()
{
    int cube = calcCube(getCubeSide());
    display(cube);
}

int getCubeSide()
{
    int cubeSide = 0;
    cout << "Please enter an integer to calculate the size of your cube: " << endl;
    cin >> cubeSide;

    return cubeSide;
}

int calcCube(int cubeSide)
{
    int cube = (cubeSide * cubeSide * cubeSide);

}

void display(int cube)
{
    cout << "The area of your cube is: " << cube << endl;
}
```

Comment: normally code-only answers are bad... but there's not much more to be said here

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are calling display method without "()" and the needed parameter. Also, you are writing "calcCube(int cubeSide);", just put there your value.